# Is there a name for the function $D(x,y) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n (x_i - y_i)$, where $x$ and $y$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, soft-question, terminology, euclidean-geometry

I am studying real analysis and encountered this function

$$D(x,y) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n (x_i - y_i)$$

where $x,y$ are $n$-dimensional vectors living in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

It is easy to show that is it not a distance.

I wonder if there is a name for this function.

Comment: I don't know about this function, but if you take absolute values instead, then this is called "Manhattan-metric".

Comment: For a reference on the Manhattan metric, see Wikipedia's ["Taxicab geometry" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry).

Comment: $\frac{1}{N}D(x,y)$ is the average difference in respective components of $x,y$.

Comment: Well but this is no metric though, in that this can be 0 for $x \not =y$. Take $n=2$ and let $x=(0,0)$ and $y=(1,-1)$. The lack of absolute value signs makes the difference.

Comment: @Mike It's also antisymmetric and not positive in general. Haven't checked if it verifies triangle inequality, but I'd bet it doesn't.

Comment: ^it's linear in $x- y$ so it must satisfy the triangle inequality (with equality).

Comment: This is just a comment, but I'd view it as the dot product $(\mathbf x-\mathbf y)\cdot \langle1,\ldots,1\rangle$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This isn't a full answer but I think it does give insight*

$|D(x,y)|$ as defined above is the shortest distance 
(Manhattan Metric) of $y$ from the **plane** $P=\{x': \sum_{i=1}^n x'_i = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \}$. The sign of $D(x,y)$ captures to which side of $P$ is $y$ on.